# In the pandas dataframe, \\ N is randomly exist and i want to remove it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I made a `pandas.dataframe`.

I got rid of `NAN` with `pandas.dropna`, but `\\N` wasn't removed by `dropna`.

Please tell me how I can get rid of it.

Comment: Try converting it to a numerical value, then you'll have a NaN to kill

Comment: Can you show a small sample dataframe? What exactly does `\\N` mean? Is that a string value you need removed? Or am I not aware of a special meaning.

Comment: sorry for late. \\N is a string value. Thanks for answer in the below! it works well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = df.replace(r'^\\N$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna()
```

---

***Code could be like:***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['test1', 1],
    ['\\N', 2],
    ['test2', 3],
    [nan, 4],
    ['\\N', 5],
    ['test3', 6]])

df = df.replace(r'^\\N$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna()
print(df)
```

---

***Result:***

```
       0  1
0  test1  1
2  test2  3
5  test3  6
```